How to encode audio buffer for mp4-muxer using only client side?
Running Vanligy mp4 muxer demo as shown on https://github.com/Vanilagy/mp4-muxer/tree/main/demo works fine on a desktop but produces an error on Android as follows:

"EncodingError: input audio buffer is incompatible with codec paramers."

Any idea on how to set audioEncoder.configure on Android chrome?
if (audioTrack) {
    audioEncoder = new AudioEncoder({
        output: (chunk, meta) => muxer.addAudioChunk(chunk, meta),
        error: e => console.error(e)
    });
    audioEncoder.configure({
        codec: 'mp4a.40.2',
        numberOfChannels: 1,
        sampleRate: audioSampleRate,
        bitrate: 128000
    });

    // Create a MediaStreamTrackProcessor to get AudioData chunks from the audio track
    let trackProcessor = new MediaStreamTrackProcessor({ track: audioTrack });
    let consumer = new WritableStream({
        write(audioData) {
            if (!recording) return;
            audioEncoder.encode(audioData);
            audioData.close();
        }
    });
    trackProcessor.readable.pipeTo(consumer);
}

Expecting to be able to do MP4 Muxing audio and video on smartphone the same way as on a desktop. The audio buffer doesn't seem to work on Android chrome using codec 'mp4a.40.2'.

I suspect Android is using Opus for audio and VP9 for video. These codecs cannot go into MP4. The only workaround I can think is to convert Opus audio into PCM then re-encode (using WebCodecs API if supported on Android browsers) into MPEG's own codecs of AAC or MP3. Then finally mux into MPEG's MP4 container.

Thanks for the reply. Anyway, the video codec and buffer work just fine and can produce a muted MP4. Waiting to see if there is a documented demo of a workaround on the audio issue.

I don't understand, is the demo not about getting a microphone recording? So a muted audio file should not be considered as "fine" since it does meet the project's expectation. (1) From looking at this code part I can see the picture part is supposed to come from a Canvas. This part works okay because WebCodecs can accept raw pixels as data to be encoded as an AVC/H264 frame. If that demo recorded the Android camera instead, then you see errors with the "incompatible" video codec too. PS: Safari/iOS records AAC and MP4

(2) Since this is WebCodecs I just realised you can just input the Opus audio chunks into some function that encodes its received input into AAC format before sending the result chunk back to that Vanilagy muxer (for packaging the audio and video as one file). You can safely skip the" decompress Opus into Raw PCM" step as that will happen automatically (by WebCodecs API) in the background during your Opus to AAC conversion. (3) Ask a new question about converting Opus to AAC with WebCodecs.
